# Определение количества потерянных пакетов при передаче данных модемом

Tags: c#, модемы, 3g

Есть 3G модем, количество потерянных пакетов при передаче данных нужно измерить. Какими средствами это можно выполнить?

Comment: Вопрос в общем-то из области физики, но. Есть максимальная скорость передачи данных для  протокола 3G. Есть текущая скорость передачи данных, замерить можно разными способами. Можно предположить, что относительное качество соединения будет выражаться отношением текущей скорости, к максимальной. Кроме того, можно считать количество, потерянных при передаче, пакетов, это немного сложнее, но больше говорит именно о качестве соединения. А можно считать с модема текущий уровень сигнала. который, в общем-то, говорит только об удаленности от базовой станции. Какие критерии качества вас интересуют?

Comment: Если так, то я бы хотел посчитать количество потерянных пакетов при передаче. Но я являюсь полным профаном в этой области, потому надеюсь, что вы подскажете хотя бы направление, в котором мне стоит следовать.

Comment: Скорректируйте вопрос, потому что в текущем виде его просто закроют как слишком общий. Я, к сожалению, в данном вопросе тоже больше теоретик, но если нормально описать критерии которые вы хотите посчитать и что вы знаете как сделать, а в чем видите проблему, то может отзовется кто-то более грамотный

Comment: А что говорит драйвер модема? По-моему, у драйвера должна быть утилита, которая такую инфу должна отдавать.

Comment: @Bulson, используется драйвер версии 2.6.2.3155 устройства usbcdcacm\Vid_12D1&Subclass_02&Prot_01 (HUAWEI Modem, конкретно модель назвать не могу). Утилиты никакой в интернете не нашел, да и документации толком тоже нет.